# Ruby - threading and queues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to run some calculations using threads and queues, can anyone help with my code below?  Does it look correct and do I need a queue?

```
  require 'thread'

  queue = Queue.new

  calculation = Thread.new do
    MyItem.find_each(start: 0, batch_size: 100) do |item|
        my_calc = ItemsCalculator.new(item)
        details_to_save = my_calc.get_details
        details_to_save.each do |dt|
          dt.save
        end
      end
  end

  puts "finished"
```

Comment: Your question will result in opinions, not specific answers, because we don't know what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult for us to judge if it's "correct" because you haven't told us what it's supposed to do.

> [Queue](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/thread/rdoc/Queue.html) provides a way to synchronize communication between
>   threads.

Are you trying to synchronize data between threads? If so then you should use a `Queue`. However, the way your code currently works you are simply creating new `Queue` object but never actually using it. Judging by your code I would guess you do not need it. It looks like you are saving your results from the calculations to the database so you don't need to send them across threads.

Comment: Thanks - no I do not need to send them across threads.  I was unsure if I needed a queue as well as threads.  I want the code to be as fats as possible.